# Show form when clicking edit on profile page in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, meteor, meteor-autoform

On many pages, I can see my user profile page and click a link to edit some information on my profile page. For instance, on Facebook I can see information about myself on the About page, and if I click edit, the small section changes to form inputs.

How can I best achieve same behaviour using `meteor-autoform`?

I can use

```
{{> quickForm id=id collection=collection fields="firstName,middleName,lastName"}}
```

to show the form.

But how can I initially hide the form and first show it when the user clicks edit? If I have 4 sections each with some information and a separate form (full name, birthday, education, work experience), should I then print 4 forms with `meteor-autoform` inside a `<div style="display:none">` element and when the user clicks edit, the div with information hides and the form is shown, and vice versa?

I guess it can be done more smooth, only rendering the forms if the user clicks edit. I just don't how to do this neatly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "meteor way" would be to use a reactive helper, which depends on a reactive value:

```
Template.profile.helpers({
  showProfileForm: function () {
    return Session.get('showProfileForm');
  }
});
```

Then in your template, instead of an ugly `display: none` you will use Handlebars:

```
{{#if showProfileForm}}
  {{> quickForm id=id collection=collection fields="firstName,middleName,lastName"}}
{{/if}}
```

From there, you can just change the state of your `showProfileForm` session variable (in an event function for example), and your helper will change its return value reactively:

```
Template.profile.onCreated(function () {
  Session.set('showProfileForm', false); // to avoid undefined at first
});

Template.profile.events({
  'click a#showHideForm': function(e, template) {
    Session.set('showProfileForm', !Session.get('showProfileForm'));
  }
});
```

If you dislike using the Session for this, David Weldon wrote [a nice piece](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/scoped-reactivity) about how to use reactive variables instead of Session variables for helpers like this one.

Comment: Very nice, OP this is your answer.

Comment: Thank you! What if I have a list of items `{{#each items}}<p>{{name}} (<a href="#" class="edit">edit</a>)</p>{{/each}}` and want to edit the items separately? So it will be something like `{{#each items}}{{#if showForm}}{{> quickForm ...}}{{else}}<p>{{name}} (<a href="#" class="edit">edit</a>)</p>{{/if}}{{/each}}` but how can I set and get for which items the forms should be shown/hidden? I guess I should store the id somehow.